# Appium tests are not performed on my Android device

Tags: java, android, maven, intellij-idea, appium

I am learning automation testing with `Appium(Lastest 1.8.2)-Mobile Automation` Testing from Scratch course on *Udemy*.
I am trying with real and virtual devices and I can launch the application, but my operation(`.click`) is not working.

I am working on `IntelliJ` IDEA Community 2019.2.

**Appium** version: v1.14.1

**I created Java Project with Maven Module
JAR:**
commons-lang3-3.0, client-combined-3.141.59, java-client, selenium-java

## My code:

**BASE CLASS:**

```
public class base {

    public static AndroidDriver Capabilities() throws MalformedURLException {

        File f = new File("src");

        File fs = new File(f, "ApiDemos-debug.apk");

        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "Galaxy Tab S2");

        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME,"UiAutomator2");

        cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, fs.getAbsolutePath());

        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), cap);

        return driver;

    }

}
```

**BASICS CLASS:**

```
public class basics extends base {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {

        AndroidDriver<AndroidElement> driver = Capabilities();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Preference']")).click();

        driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='3. Preference dependencies']").click();

        driver.findElementById("android:id/checkbox").click();

    }

}
```

The problem is that I am receiving (probably) good exit code in Appium:

Got response with status 200

But I cannot see that test is performed on my device with Android.

Did I omit something?

Comment: so what you need to fugure out first is if it is even recognizing the element..is it even trying to do the click() function im assuming if its not working/not seeing the element you are getting some sort of error what is your console output after runing the test?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that many dependencies, it is quite enough to have [`io.appium.java-client`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client) only, Appium Java Client **includes** Selenium libraries and guaranteed to work only with the version which it's linked with

[image]

So

1. First of all try to remove all the dependencies apart from the Appium Java Client.
2. Explicitly set up the following [Desired Capabilities](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/#android-only):

   - `MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME` with the value of `android`
   - `AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE` with the value of your application package
   - `AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY` with the value of your application activity
   - `MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME` should be `uiautomator2`

You can check out [Appium -> Code Examples -> Java](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Java) for comprehensive information and sample code repository which you can use as the "skeleton" for your test

Comment: This solution didn't work. Still having those exceptions:

INFO: Detected dialect: W3C

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/codec/w3c/W3CHttpCommandCodec